# Why result of the addition not captured in iteration?

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

In the given code, why the result of the
addition is not captured in iteration? Why x's value never changes?

```
public class Fortran {
    static int bump(int i) { return i + 2; }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; bump(x))
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Change the last line in your for statement to read x =bump(x). You're not capturing the result.

Answer (score 3):

1. Java passes values by copying, so `bump` only gets a copy of `x`
2. The value returned by `bump` is never assigned to `x` (perhaps you forgot `x =`).

Perhaps try

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x = bump(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just cause your new value is never assigned.
The correct way of doing that is more.

```
for(int x=0;x<5;x+=2)
{
    //do whatever you want
}
```

NB : x+=2 is a short writing for x=x+2